# Python Data frame read json and filter data from dataframe

Tags: python, django, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe

I have json format like this

```
  {
  "2015": [
    {
      "DayofWeek": 4,
      "Date": "2015-02-06 00:00:00",
      "Year": 2015,
      "y": 43.2,
      "x": 10.397
    }
  ],
  "2016": [
    {
      "DayofWeek": 4,
      "Date": "2016-02-06 00:00:00",
      "Year": 2016,
      "y": 43.2,
      "x": 10.397,
      "Minute": 0
    }
  ],
  "2017": [
    {
      "DayofWeek": 4,
      "Date": "2017-02-06 00:00:00",
      "Year": 2017,
      "y": 43.2,
      "x": 10.397,
      "Minute": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

I am reading JSON file like this, and after reading json file; converting it to data frame

```
 with open('sample.json') as json_data:
    data = json.load(json_data)

df=pd.DataFrame([data])
```

Now, I want filter data based on certain input key value like DayofWeek and Year etc.

**Example:**

**Case1:**

if input value is DayofWeek=4, then I want filter all objects having DayofWeek=4.

**Case2:**

if input value is both DayofWeek=4 and year=2017, then I want filter all the 2017 years data from json having DayofWeek=4.

I have tried this code, but it is not working

```
filteredVal=df['2017']
filter_v={'2015':{'DayofYear':4}}
pd.Series(filter_v)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension like this:

```
[data[x] for x in data if data[x][0]['DayofWeek'] == 4 and data[x][0]['Year'] == 2017]
```

This will give you a list of dictionary entries. If you want a filtered dictionary (to convert to a DataFrame), you can instead do something like this:

```
filtered_data = {}
filtered_data.update([(x, data[x]) for x in data if data[x][0]['DayofWeek'] == 4 and data[x][0]['Year'] == 2017])
```

Comment: I have tried you approach, but got this error
 [df[x] for x in df if df[x][0]['DayofWeek'] == 4 and df[x][0]['Year'] == 2017]
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Comment: Sorry, it should have said data not df. This works with the dictionary, not the pandas DataFrame. You can convert the filtered list of dictionary entries to a DataFrame after filtering (see edited response)

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is, your json-values contains lists with dicts:

```
data
>>
{'2015': [{'DayofWeek': 4,
   'Date': '2015-02-06 00:00:00',
   'Year': 2015,
   'y': 43.2,
   'x': 10.397}],
 '2016': [{'DayofWeek': 4,
   'Date': '2016-02-06 00:00:00',
   'Year': 2016,
   'y': 43.2,
   'x': 10.397,
   'Minute': 0}],
 '2017': [{'DayofWeek': 4,
   'Date': '2017-02-06 00:00:00',
   'Year': 2017,
   'y': 43.2,
   'x': 10.397,
   'Minute': 0}]}
```

...pandas cannot process this (as far as I know).

But if every list contains just 1 element, you can convert it:

```
data_dict = {d: data[d][0] for d in data}
data_dict
>>
{'2015': {'DayofWeek': 4,
  'Date': '2015-02-06 00:00:00',
  'Year': 2015,
  'y': 43.2,
  'x': 10.397},
 '2016': {'DayofWeek': 4,
  'Date': '2016-02-06 00:00:00',
  'Year': 2016,
  'y': 43.2,
  'x': 10.397,
  'Minute': 0},
 '2017': {'DayofWeek': 4,
  'Date': '2017-02-06 00:00:00',
  'Year': 2017,
  'y': 43.2,
  'x': 10.397,
  'Minute': 0}}
```

Now you can make a `DataFrame` of it, with the `index` orientation:

```
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data_dict, orient='index')
df
```

[image]

And access your elements:

Case1:

```
df[df['DayofWeek']==4]
```

Case2:

```
df[(df['DayofWeek']==4) & (df['Year']==2017)]
```

[image]

**EDIT**

If you have multiple elements inside the list, you can just create a list of all entries:

```
data_list = [v for d in data for v in data[d]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data_list)
```

Since you have a `Year` column, you probably don't even need the json-/dict-key, so I just skipped it. :-)

Comment: every list contains more than one element, it is very big json.

Answer (score 0):

Data you have is not consistent, but apparently pandas can handle this.

[`pandas.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) works with nested lists inside dictionaries (see also `record_path` parameter to it), and [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) will efficiently join separate DataFrames together:

```
import pandas
import json

with open('sample.json') as json_data:
    data = json.load(json_data)

df = pandas.concat([pandas.json_normalize(v) for v in data.values()], ignore_index=True)

# Case 1:
df[df['DayofWeek'] == 4]

# Result:
#    DayofWeek                 Date  Year     y       x  Minute
# 0          4  2015-02-06 00:00:00  2015  43.2  10.397     NaN
# 1          4  2016-02-06 00:00:00  2016  43.2  10.397     0.0
# 2          4  2017-02-06 00:00:00  2017  43.2  10.397     0.0

# Case 2:
df[(df['DayofWeek'] == 4) & (df['Year'] == 2017)]

#   DayofWeek                 Date  Year     y       x  Minute
# 2          4  2017-02-06 00:00:00  2017  43.2  10.397     0.0
```